# Boxplot: colors by x value and hues differentiated by pattern

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn

Say I have a boxplot like the one shown below:

[image: example]

I would like to achieve a different coloring:

- `Fri`, `Sat` and `Sun` would be colored blue; `Thur` would be colored red
- I would like to differentiate hues with a pattern in the box (stripped or something)

I can't find a way to do this manipulation using seaborn palette.

I know I can mess with the boxes of a boxplot in matplotlib directly but seaborn gives me the axes back. How can I get the boxes in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes end up in the `artists` list on the returned axes, so you just need to manipulate the attributes on those objects:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(data=x)
box = ax.artists[0]
box. set_facecolor("white")
```

etc.