# Use same color for all grouped bars in Seaborn barplot

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

The following code produces a barchart with differently colored bars for each "hue" value associated with the grouping variable `y`:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.barplot(x=[3, 7, 12, 10], y=list("AABB"), hue=list("XYXY"))
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart using <code>y</code> as a grouping variable]

I want to change the colors so that all bars belonging to the same grouping value have the same color. That is, the first two bars where `y == "A"` should be orange, and the last two bars where `y == "B"` should be blue.

I've tried the `palette` argument of `sns.barplot(). However, unless I'm missing something, this allows me to specify the color of each hue level, but not separately for the values of the grouping variable.

I've also had a look at the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206474/boxplot-colors-by-x-value-and-hues-differentiated-by-pattern), which asks something similar about box-whisker plots created by `sns.boxplot()`. The accepted answer suggests to access the rectangles representing the bars using the `artists` property of the axes. However, it seems that `sns.barplot()` doesn't use `artists` in the same way as `sns.boxplot()`: `ax.artists` appears always to be an empty list:

```py
print(ax.artists)
[]
```

So, what do I have to change so that the top two bars appear in blue, and the bottom two bars appear in orange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bars are not in `artists` but in `patches`. So you may loop over `ax.patches` and set the colors to your liking.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.barplot(x=[3, 7, 12, 10], y=list("AABB"), hue=list("XYXY"))
for i, bar in enumerate(ax.patches):
    bar.set_color("C{}".format(i%2))
plt.show()
```

[image]